# Getting Data from a Data Bound Map View Item's Context Menu

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, bing-maps

I'm writing a Windows Phone application that shows a number of locations on a map. These positions have phone numbers, twitter accounts and websites associated with them.

What I want to do is add a context menu to the items that allows the user to open the websites, view twitter or call the phone number. However, with a MapItemsControl their is no easy way to get the current item.

I am looking for some way to do this in as painless a way as possible.

Some code:

```
<mi:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapPins" ItemsSource="{Binding Pushpins}">
    <mi:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <mi:Pushpin Location="{Binding Location}">
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu IsEnabled="{Binding ShowContext}" >
                        <TextBlock Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=image}" Text="Show Menu"/>
                        <TextBlock Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=image1}" Text="Open Webpage" Tap="EOpenWeb" />
                        <StackPanel Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=image2}" Orientation="Horizontal" Tap="ECallPhone">
                            <TextBlock Text="Call "/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Contact.FormattedPhone}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Opacity="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=image3}" Text="On Twitter" Tap="EOpenTwitter" />
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"  Text="{Binding Name}" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-6" Visibility="{Binding ShowGlyphs}">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding HereNow}" Visibility="{Binding ShowHere}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Width="48" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Image x:Name="image" Height="48" Opacity="{Binding HasMenu}" Source="locationGlyphs/appbar.book.open.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        <Image x:Name="image1" Height="48" Opacity="{Binding HasWeb}" Source="locationGlyphs/appbar.link.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="48"/>
                        <Image x:Name="image2" Height="48" Opacity="{Binding HasPhone}" Source="locationGlyphs/appbar.phone.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="48"/>
                        <Image x:Name="image3" Height="48" Opacity="{Binding HasTwitter}" Source="locationGlyphs/appbar.twitter.bird.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="48"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </mi:Pushpin>
        </DataTemplate>
    </mi:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</mi:MapItemsControl>
```

That details how the objects are drawn to the map. The Pushpins list is just an Observable Collection of my data.

If this was a ListBox I could simply use the SelectedItem or similar to resolve this, but that doesn't seem an option for MapItemsControl. Has anyone managed to do this successfully? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow react to the tap on the pushpin. You have a contextmenu and you clearly need to go that way at the moment.  needs to have a tap event handler attached:

```
<mi:Pushpin
Location="{Binding Location}" Tap="Pushpin_Tap">
```

Pushpin_Tap event handler needs to be managed similar to this:

```
private void Pushpin_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var _ppmodel = sender as Pushpin;
    ContextMenu contextMenu = 
        ContextMenuService.GetContextMenu(_ppmodel);
    contextMenu.DataContext = _viewModel.Pushpins.Where
    (c => (c.Location 
        == _ppmodel.Location)).FirstOrDefault();

    // this way you can find which pushpin/position was tapped by finding the 
    // one which has the same location in your Pushpins observable collection

    if (contextMenu.Parent == null)
    {
        contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

I wrote about showing a [context menu on pushpin tap](http://igrali.com/2012/01/07/show-a-tooltip-for-tapped-pushpin-on-windows-phone/) on my blog, so if you wish you can go and read the whole story there.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. The only issue I can see is that holding to open the ContextMenu might cause some problems. I think I can fix that though. Thanks again!

Comment: @Runewake2 this opens the contextmenu on tap, which is even better ;)

Comment: Yes, but it might introduce some weird stuff if the user holds the pushpin as to my knowledge the tap event wouldn't be called then. Yes, the hold event is still called and breaks everything. Any idea to avoid this?